# Entity Framework 6 with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, frameworks, entity, sharepoint-2013, entity-framework-6

I tried without success to get a SharePoint 2013 application page or web part to work with Entity Framework 6 (6.0.1 to be exact - the version installed into Visual Studio 2012 by default using NuGet at time of writing).

My code was very simple for test purposes, just reading data from one table.

I could install the package just fine, create models, see that the they were properly configured etc, no problem - but whenever I tried to load the page I got the error:

Event code: 3008
Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException
Exception message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\[sitename]\web.config line 36)

I copied all of the config settings from the App.Config file in VS (created by the EF install), into the web.config, verbatim.

I tried every suggested fix I could find on the interweb (e.g. changing the EF assembly ref to "Specific version = false", changing version refs in the config file to the specific version... all sorts) but nothing worked.

I created a console app using the same settings and it worked fine, so I know it's not a server-specific issue - looks like a compatibility issue with SP2013, anyone have any ideas?

I installed EF 5 using the NuGet console, and finally got it working with that... but I'm very curious as to why EF 6 refused to play ball.

Thanks
Poolio

Comment: EF6 is not binary compatible with EF5 so if sharepoint is expecting EF5 types (I have the feeling that this is the case) and you give it EF6 it just won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy the Entity Framework assemblies (EntityFramework.dll, EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll) as part of your SharePoint solution package. You can reference external dlls in the package.